# Is there a way to change which location Factor looks for Homebrew libraries in?

Tags: homebrew, factor-lang

I'm trying to use the disassembler capstone library in Factor but I get an error that Factor can't find the library:

```
Loading resource:basis/tools/disassembler/capstone/capstone.factor
IN: scratchpad : hello ( -- ) "hello" print ;
IN: scratchpad \ hello disassemble
Cannot resolve C library function
Library: DLL" libcapstone.dylib"
Symbol: cs_open
DlError: dlopen(libcapstone.dylib, 0x0009): tried: 'libcapstone.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcapstone.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcapstone.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libcapstone.dylib' (no such file)
See https://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Factor/Requirements
```

But Homebrew on Apple Silicon installs in /opt/homebrew/ not /usr/lib

Is there a way to change the location Factor looks for libraries in or the location that Homebrew installs libraries? I tried to copy the file as well but it didn't work (even with sudo):

command: `cp /opt/homebrew/libcapstone.dylib /usr/lib/libcapstone.dylib`

result: `cp: /usr/lib/libcapstone.dylib: Operation not permitted`

Comment: What if you create a symlink under `/usr/local/lib` (you don't need sudo for that)?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar macOS applications won't look under `/usr/local/lib` for dynamic libraries by default. It will look under `/usr/lib`, but that path is under System Integrity Protection (not even root can change it without changing boot options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to my own question after some trial and error and help from the Factor Discord.

- If running on an `arm64` machine (assuming Factor still doesn't have an `arm64` compiler), your `libcapstone.dylib` will likely be in `/opt/homebrew` instead of in `/usr/lib` where Factor expects it.

  - To fix this you must first install the `x86_64` version of homebrew on your machine (https://gist.github.com/progrium/b286cd8c82ce0825b2eb3b0b3a0720a0) , and then `arch -x86_64 brew reinstall capstone` and rebuild Factor `arch -x86_64 ./build.sh update`

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is 1) it's pretty hard to change the default list of directories that macOS applications will look into to find dynamic libraries, and 2) the directories on that default list are protected by System Integrity Protection (this is why you can't move a library into `/usr/lib`).

So if you want to fix this you're going to either have to hack around where applications look for dynamic libraries or disable system integrity protection. Disabling system integrity protection is a pain, so I went with the first one. It's a bit ugly but it gets the job done:

You can set the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to change the search path of dynamically loaded libraries (some sources will use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I found this breaks Factor). The only problem with this is that you have to call Factor from the command line every time. The ugly part is that you need to set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/opt/lib` every time you want to run Factor.

To partially alleviate/automate this, I have this script in my PATH that just calls the GUI app with the environment variable set to Homebrew's library path:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/lib" /Applications/factor/Factor.app/Contents/MacOS/factor
```

I named this file `factor-fix`, ran `chmod +x factor-fix`, and put it in `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo mv factor-fix /usr/local/bin` (note the `sudo`, this must be done as root). Now I can run `factor-fix` from the command line and it'll find Homebrew's libraries and open the GUI.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks so much for the detailed response! I've completed these steps and created a `factor-fix` file in `/usr/local/bin` with the following contents:


`#!/bin/sh

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib"
/Users/davidenders/Desktop/CLINIC/factor/Factor.app/Contents/MacOS/factor`

This didn't work though, nor did setting the env. variables and opening Factor normally. I built Factor from source as I am contributing to the project so it is on my desktop in a repo instead of in Applications - maybe this is the problem? Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: @DavidEnders Odd, this works for me and just tried it with a newly built Factor from source. Just to double check: are you sure does `/opt/homebrew/lib/libcapstone.dylib` (if not, then try installing or reinstalling it from homebrew)? Because it works for me, I don't think having the executable outside of `/Applications` is the problem.

Comment: Hey Michael, turns out the fix was even a bit simpler. I installed the x86 version of Homebrew on my M1 Macbook, then ran `arch -x86_64 brew reinstall capstone` which put the library in the correct location, then rebuilt Factor with `arch -x86_64 ./build.sh update`. Thanks so much for your help!